# TinyMCE link tool - how to add CSS styles to links dynamicaly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have searched around but wasn't able to find a solution.

What I want to find out is a way to edit the tinyMce link plugin (or make an edited copy of it) to work in a way that adds specific styling within the link tag, and the ability to specify in the initialization of the plugin what style to add, so that it can be done dynamically. So that I can have result like this(for example):

```
<a style="color:#00FFFF" href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Any solutions for this? Or a point in the best general direction?

Thanks

Comment: the color should change depending on what?

Comment: a hidden input field, for example. Or based on a variable in the plugin initialization.

Comment: do you want to have all links in the editor to have the same colour then?

Comment: Good question! I would prefer the ability to decide on a per link basis.

Comment: I just realized what I said. If it's based on an input field, then of course all of them would have to be the same. The thing is, I might be able to change the hidden field value beforehand with jQuery, so having the style linked to a variable is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case i think the best is to wait until the link has been inserted and then do the following action assuming your color has been set in the tinymce init like `my_link_color: 'green',`

```
$(ed.getBody()).find('a').attr('style','color:'+ed.getParam("my_link_color"));
```

Comment: +1, this definitely looks like something I can use after some modification. I'll just wait a little to see if I get more answers, and will test this solution in the meantime before accepting the answer. Thanks!